# NPM install throws error internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800 throw err;

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I tried all the solutions. but it doesn't work.

I deleted the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file,
and then I tried to run `$ npm install`

```
npm install
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
```

Comment: add the error screenshot

Comment: Please write your npm and node version by running `npm -v` and `node -v`, and paste your `package.json`

Comment: The fact that error is referring to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` Makes me wonder if you have actually deleted the node_modules under the Node installation itself, which the system would need. Is it possible that you check after reinstalling node again?

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands

```
 rm -rf node_modules
 npm install
```

still not working then upgrade your node version and npm package